# how to create motion of text along Path animation in winrt application?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

how to create  motion of text along Path animation in winrt application? After a bit of searching in silverlight and wpf i found PathListBox to do this kind of animation!
But I could not able to find **PathListBox** for Winrt applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the control here http://pathtextblock.codeplex.com/. may be it should work

Comment: Did you get this control to work on Windows 8.1 or 8.0 @pashaplus?