# How can I animate text on a circular path in winrt?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to animate a text on a circular path in a Windows Store App (with C#) for Win8.1.
Although there are some examples on the internet on how to do it with Silverlight and WPF, those don't seem to work at all in WinRT (missing a lot of methods for example).

When searching for a solution I also found the Stackoverflow question below, but it only applies to Windows 8.0 and not Windows 8.1, so I was unable to get it working.

[how to create motion of text along Path animation in winrt application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156368/how-to-create-motion-of-text-along-path-animation-in-winrt-application)

Is there any solution for this without re-implementing everything from scratch?

Comment: I thought [this](http://studentguru.gr/b/kaisaras89/archive/2013/02/23/enabling-an-element-to-animate-on-a-path-on-windows-8-store-apps-i-e-making-a-pathlistbox-layoutpath-for-windows-rt) was pretty neat for providing a LayoutPath alternative in RT, haven't had a chance to use it though so is just a comment.

Comment: Good tip, I'll probably have to implement some solution so that the letters "rotate" on the curves one by one and not the entire TextBlock as a whole, but still it could be a good start. Thanks

Comment: Ya if you're going with individual letters it gets a lot easier, just set an ellipse as a guide, position them and set your rotation transforms in a storyboard, no sweat. LayoutPath was handy in scenarios past though for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`CascadingTextBlock`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Controls/CascadingTextBlock/CascadingTextBlock.xaml.cs) control in WinRT XAML Toolkit for an example how to break up one `TextBlock` into multiple. You'd just need to change the way the transforms are animated.
If your text is a constant string - it might be best to just create the animation in Blend - arrange multiple single letter `TextBlocks` on a circle and design the animation using the provided tools.

Comment: It's not a constant string, but your CascadingTexBlock tip it's a useful one, I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working? it is purely a XAML Solution. The Storyboard starts at load.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
   <Window.Resources>
          <Storyboard x:Key="Rotate">
                 <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="Label1">
                       <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                       <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="360"/>
                 </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          </Storyboard>
   </Window.Resources>
   <Window.Triggers>
          <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                 <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Rotate}"/>
          </EventTrigger>
   </Window.Triggers>
<Grid>
   <Label x:Name="Label1" Content="WordsAndStuff" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="218.388,112.806,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.509,1.782">
          <Label.RenderTransform>
                 <TransformGroup>
                       <ScaleTransform/>
                       <SkewTransform/>
                       <RotateTransform/>
                       <TranslateTransform/>
                 </TransformGroup>
          </Label.RenderTransform>
   </Label>

</Grid>
```

Comment: That's neat, but it's a WPF solution instead of WinRT/XAML and it works on a single label instead of separate letters.